# POSIX semaphores between child and parent processes

Tags: c, process, posix, semaphore

Im trying to learn semaphores and how they work between processes, so i wanted to create a program that prints 10 times the string "abcd" from two separate for() loops. One for() contains the "ab" string while the other one contains the "cd" string. I thought the code was fine but apparently its not. I would appreciate if you could point out anything wrong or if i got something misunderstood.

Here's the code:

```
int main(void)
{

int i;
char *p;
sem_t *sem; //First semaphore
sem_t *sem2; //Second semaphore

//create, initialize semaphores
sem = sem_open("/semaphore1", O_CREAT,  0644, 1);
sem2 = sem_open("/semaphore2", O_CREAT,  0644, 1);

if (fork()) //Child process
{
     for (i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
        sem_wait(sem2); //Lock the semaphore
        for (p="ab"; *p; p++)
        {
            write(1, p, 1);
            usleep(100);
        }
        sem_post(sem); //Release the semaphore lock
     }
     wait(NULL);
}
else //Parent process
{
     for (i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
        sem_wait(sem); //Lock the semaphore
        for (p="cd\n"; *p; p++)
        {
            write(1, p, 1);
            usleep(100);
        }
        sem_post(sem2); //Release the semaphore lock
     }
}

//Close the Semaphores
sem_close(sem);
sem_unlink("/semaphore1");
sem_close(sem2);
sem_unlink("/semaphore2");
return 0;
}
```

And one of the outputs:

```
abcd
cadb
cadb
cadb
cabd
cabd
cabd
cadb
cabd
cadb
```

Comment: You need to initialize one of the semaphores with zero instead of both with one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks! that helped a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in a comment, you need to initialize the first semaphore (renamed `sem1` for symmetry with `sem2` in the code below) to `0` instead of `1` so that the parent process gets to go first.

The child and parent process comments were misplaced (the parent gets a non-zero result from `fork()` and so works in the `if`).  This version produces the desired output even without any calls to `usleep()`.  Nominally, only one of the processes needs to use `sem_close()` and `sem_unlink()`, but since you don't check for or report any errors, you don't notice the calls that fail.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char *p;
    sem_t *sem1; // First semaphore
    sem_t *sem2; // Second semaphore

    // create, initialize semaphores
    sem1 = sem_open("/semaphore1", O_CREAT,  0644, 0);
    sem2 = sem_open("/semaphore2", O_CREAT,  0644, 1);

    if (fork()) // Parent process
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            sem_wait(sem2); // Lock the semaphore
            for (p = "ab"; *p; p++)
            {
                write(1, p, 1);
                //usleep(100);
            }
            sem_post(sem1); // Release the semaphore lock
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }
    else // Child process
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            sem_wait(sem1); // Lock the semaphore
            for (p = "cd\n"; *p; p++)
            {
                write(1, p, 1);
                //usleep(100);
            }
            sem_post(sem2); // Release the semaphore lock
        }
    }

    // Close the Semaphores
    sem_close(sem1);
    sem_unlink("/semaphore1");
    sem_close(sem2);
    sem_unlink("/semaphore2");
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

Comment: That's the answer i was looking for!